# How to change the background style of TabView?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When including a 3D plot inside a TabView, in my computer, the entire tab is grayed as if it was a giant button, leaving the Graphics with a white background:

[image: example]

To avoid the contrast between the gray and the white, I would prefer that the tab also had a white color.

Tried `BaseStyle -> {Background -> White}` but with no success (only the borders get restyled).

How can I change the Background color of the tab?

Comment: Graphics have transparent background by default, not white, so there won't be a noticeable border around the graphics.  Could you post a graphical example showing more clearly what you need, and also include the full question in the post body (not just title)?

Comment: You are right, but I imported a 3D stl file, and it shows with a white background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default background is not white but transparent for graphics, so there's no harsh contrast.  `Background -> White` makes the background white and leaves the borders, quite the opposite of what you said.  `BaseStyle` doesn't seem to do anything.

This is what I get on Windows XP:

[image: TabView]

**EDIT:** An alternative is a custom `TabView`-implementation along the following lines:

```
objects = Table[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}], {f, {Sin, Cos, Exp}}];

Column[
 {SetterBar[Dynamic[x], Thread[objects -> Range@Length[objects]]], 
  Dynamic[x]}
 ]
```

This is unfinished, but the basics work, and it shows you how to do it yourself.

Comment: I don't know why I went straight to the BaseStyle (a help thing I guess...). In my XP it works just like you stated. Thanks for reminding me of my limited capacities...

Comment: @P.Fonseca You're right, 3D objects always have a white background here.  But as Heike pointed out, this only works on Windows, and it's ugly too.  So you may want to go with a custom `TabView` implementation.  See my edit to see how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an OS specific problem. On OS X, `TabView` does have a grey background  (albeit very light), even with `Background->White`. For example

```
TabView[Table[Plot[Sin[i x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> White], {i, 4}], 
  Background->White]
```

produces this

[image]

Comment: Classic Windows controls can be styled with arbitrary colours.  It seems this is what Mathematica does: it reverts to ugly classic Windows controls.  At least on XP.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm Heike's assertion for Windows 7.

---

If you wish to always overwrite the system theme color for `TabView` boxes, you may evaluate:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd,
  TabViewBoxOptions -> {Background -> GrayLevel[1]}
]
```

---

Using either the "Windows 7 Basic" or "Windows 7 Aero" theme, I see this:

[image]

However, using the "Windows Classic" theme I see this:

[image]

If, using the Classic theme, I open `Window Color and Appearance` and change the `3D Objects` `Color 1` to white, I see:

[image]